# CreatePlaylist in soundmanager2

Tags: soundmanager2

How to create a playlist in **soundmanager2** using data from a **json** object or an **array**?
Does soundmanager2 has native playlist tools or do i have to write my own code like *createsound*() and *destroysound*() for each record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want a [Muxtape-style playlist](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/page-player/), you're going to have to make one yourself.